# Firebase imports not working (Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: initializeApp)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am hosting my website using npm, but when I load  the page this is the error I get.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: initializeApp      main.jsx:6:10`

These are all of my imports:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './src/App.jsx'
import './style.css';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

I am following this tutorial: https://fireship.io/lessons/webrtc-firebase-video-chat/
Which uses this repo: https://github.com/fireship-io/webrtc-firebase-demo

I have tried following the steps on the firebase website (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) but still doesn't work.

Comment: That project uses the legacy version of the Firebase SDK (~v8.2). The SDK's methods were drastically changed in v9 (currently on v10.7), so you will need to follow the [upgrade documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) to make it compatible with the modern modular SDK.